# ASP.NET Table Cells Formatting

Tags: asp.net

I am using an asp:Table to keep objects on my page in the correct spot, relative to each other.  However, for this page, I need to use a table that has different rows, with a different number of cells, but still be sized/formatted correctly.

I.E

I have one table, with two rows - row 0 has two cells, 00 and 01, and row 1 has one cell, 10.

Currently, the way this gets formatted is as follows:

[Row 0 - [Cell 00] [Cell 01]]

[Row 1 - [Cell 10] -----------]

However, what I want is this:

[Row 0 - [Cell 00] [Cell 01]]

[Row 1 - [----- Cell 10 -----]]

Basically, the default formatting is to keep the columns aligned, but I want the total width of the table to stay the same, and stretch the cells to fit.

I tried to set the width of the cells in row 0 to 50%, and the width of the cell in row 1 to 100%, but that still results in my first example from above.

Comment: which control are you using? have you tried  columnspan <asp:tablecell columnspan="2"> for row 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try columnspan for merging two cell like as below:

```
<asp:table runat="server" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
 <asp:tablerow>
   <asp:tablecell columnspan="2">

     Merge cell : display Header here
   </asp:tablecell>
 </asp:tablerow>
 <asp:tablerow>
  <asp:tablecell>Cell1</asp:tablecell>
  <asp:tablecell>Cell2</asp:tablecell>
 </asp:tablerow>
</asp:table>
```

Comment: yep, that columnspan property did it. Learn something new every day, I guess